# Is it under the bluedroid Android HAL still possible to get the RSSI of a paired or connected Android device?

Tags: android, c, bluetooth, android-ndk, hal

I am trying to get the Bluetooth RSSI of a paired device in under one second.
I found some interesting approaches on this site here targeting this topic.
As far as I can conclude getting the RSSI under my circumstances is not possible with the Android SDK.

But I still have - because of some papers - some hope left, that it is still possible with the NDK to use some native code of the new bluedroid HAL stack.

I am using original Samsung Galaxy Nexus I9250 for my university project.

So can someone please tell me, if it is still possible to get this value in this or a similar way?

And if yes, how it can be roughly done, because I am pretty new to C and the Android NDK.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use native API as you means NDK and call functions provided by Bluez API,please found at http://www.bluez.org/ .`hci_read_rssi()` named function provide by Bluez to get Bluetooth RSSI.( in libbluetooth.so).

to know how to use above function  please go through http://www.bluez.org/download/.

Also another link which might be help you.

http://techtitude.blogspot.pt/2013/01/tutorial-to-continuously-measure.html